# Fastest way to transform AND transpose byte[] of 32bit image data in 24bit array image data?

Tags: c#, image, pointers, optimization, unsafe

I would like to know if someone can think about a better solution for doing this stuff.

I have an array of raw bitmap data in 32bit format (RGBA)

I need to transform **and** transpose this array in an 24bit format by eliminating the alpha component.

Additionally i need to transform the data by aligning the red component in the first part of the result array, the green in after the first 1/3 and the blue after the 2/3  because i'm doing an RLE compression after.

By doing this alignment, i have a better compression because there is more chance to have red,green and blue component alignment between pixels.

I'm using unsafe and fixed pointer to do that. I'm getting something like 11ms to process for a 8.3M array length. It seems to be low but i m doing a realtime screengrabbing and every ms is counting...

(I bypass unsafe and fixed byte* stuff):

```
byte* actualpointeur = actual == (IntPtr)pd1 ? pd1 : pd2; // it s the pointer on my source 32bit array
// pd24b is a pointer to my reception array at the right size...
byte* redindexp = pd24b;
byte* greenindexp = pd24b+(datain24format.Length / 3);
byte* blueindexp = pd24b+((datain24format.Length / 3) * 2);
for (int i = 0; i < datalenght; i += 4, actualpointeur+=4, redindexp++, greenindexp++, blueindexp++)
{
    *redindexp= *(actualpointeur);
    *greenindexp = *(actualpointeur+1);
    *blueindexp = *(actualpointeur+2);
}
```

**Update**

I have done what hans is suggesting by using a int* instead of a byte* and inverse the loop to go from end to zero (comparaison again zero is faster)
It's a little bit better (first algo done in ~32000 ticks, second is done in ~31000 ticks)

```
 // it s the pointer on my source 32bit array
 int* actualpointeur = actual == (IntPtr)pd1 ? (int*)pd1 + (datalenght / 4) - 1 : (int*)pd2 + (datalenght / 4) - 1; 

 // pd24b is a pointer to my reception array at the right size...
 byte* redindexp = (pd24b + (datain24format.Length / 3)) - 1;
 byte* greenindexp = (pd24b + (datain24format.Length / 3) * 2) - 1;
 byte* blueindexp = (pd24b + datain24format.Length) - 1;
 for (int i = datalenght - 1; i >= 0; i -= 4, actualpointeur--, redindexp--, greenindexp--, blueindexp--)
 {
       *redindexp = (byte)*(actualpointeur);
       *greenindexp = (byte)(*(actualpointeur) >> 8);
       *blueindexp = (byte)(*(actualpointeur) >> 16);
 }
```

**Update 2**

With loop unrolling by 16 pixel has PFM suggest (without the test on datalength) i get now 5ms (~15000) which is a big improvement...having more than 16 give no more improvement

my new loop is :

```
for (int i = _DataLenght - 1; i >= 0; i -= 64,  actualpointeur-=16,redindexp-=16,greenindexp-=16,blueindexp-=16)
{
     *redindexp = (byte)*(actualpointeur);
     *greenindexp = (byte)(*(actualpointeur) >> 8);
     *blueindexp = (byte)(*(actualpointeur) >> 16);
     *(redindexp-1) = (byte)*(actualpointeur-1);
     *(greenindexp-1) = (byte)(*(actualpointeur-1) >> 8);
     *(blueindexp-1) = (byte)(*(actualpointeur-1) >> 16);
     ...
     *(redindexp - 15) = (byte)*(actualpointeur - 15);
     *(greenindexp - 15) = (byte)(*(actualpointeur - 15) >> 8);
     *(blueindexp - 15) = (byte)(*(actualpointeur - 15) >> 16);                                
}
```

I'm started to look with the gpu...

Comment: Either way this looks more like a question for codereview.se but I'm not sure its on-topic there either

Comment: this is c#... You can use pointer by using unsafe code. well, i just want to know if someone has an idea about this.. i tried other possibility without pointer etc ... but this is the most performing i can obtain...

Comment: apologies... I'm still not sure if this is an on topic question or not however

Comment: If the code works correctly and is given enough context this would be on-topic on Code Review. It might be a good idea to include this code in its habitat, e.g. how it is used in your code. If you decide to post on Code Review then you probably will want to delete it from Stack Overflow.

Comment: i post it on code review...

Comment: Code like this is throttled by the speed of the memory bus, not the speed of the code.  It is a bit clumsy, you've got 6 accesses per pixel, you can reduce it to 4 using int* instead of byte*.  As good as it gets.  DDR4 is nice.

Comment: You can do some loop unrolling, processing 4 or 8 pixels per cycle. You then need to add some logic for the remaining pixels if (datalenght/4) % 4 is not 0. (or % 8 if you process 8 pixels per cycle).

Comment: PFM i tried the loop unrolling by 16 pixel  but i m not using the if(datalength/4) %4 wich i think is more consomable.  Im getting now 5 ms to do the job :)